# Electron doesn't fire click() on setThumbarButtons

Tags: javascript, electron

Electron Version: 2.0.0.beta-7 (Nuxt js template)
I want to add buttons to thumbar. Images appear, but click() function doesn't working.
My code is simple:

```
win = new electron.BrowserWindow({
    icon: path.join(__dirname, 'static/icon.png'),
    width: 1380,
    height: 720,
    minWidth: 1380,
    minHeight: 720,
    frame: false,
    backgroundColor: "#141414"
});

win.setThumbarButtons([
    {
        tooltip: "Previous",
        icon: "./thumbnails/prev.png",
        click() { console.log(true); win.webContents.send("mediaprevtrack"); }
    },
    {
        tooltip: "Play / Pause",
        icon: "./thumbnails/play.png",
        click() { console.log(true); win.webContents.send("mediaplaypause"); }
    },
    {
        tooltip: "Next",
        icon: "./thumbnails/next.png",
        click() { console.log(true); win.webContents.send("medianexttrack"); }
    }
]);
```

What I should to do?

Comment: That's a pretty old version of Electron. v7 is just around the corner now.. Is it viable to use a newer version?

Comment: I tried updating Electron, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug. See https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/20556

Unsure if it's going to be resolved or not for v7.